# Allow a user to select a location by marker or entering the address

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Looking at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple I still can't understand how I can give a user the ability to **select** a location either by dragging and dropping a marker or by entering the address and then show the selected location by clicking on a button.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Select a location? or select a driving direction start or end point? What are you trying to do is unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle the map click event and get the *lat* *lng* and also create a marker and show it on the map.

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function( event ){
      alert( "Latitude: "+event.latLng.lat()+" "+", longitude: "+event.latLng.lng() ); 

  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(event.latLng.lat(),event.latLng.lng() );
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Hello World!'
  });
    });
```

Use *myLatLng* to calculate the distance.
Additionally, if you want to show a marker when user hovers over the map handle the *mouseover* event of the map.
For a list of events see here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events